# While upgrading MVC4 to MVC5,it says 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' does not contain a defination for Configure '

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

While upgrading my `MVC 4` application to `MVC 5`, I found that I have to upgrade from Web API to Web API 2, in global.asax ,i.e.

`WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` to `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

But when I did it,I got a compiler error saying

> System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' does not contain a definition for
>   Configure.

I have already mentioned a using statement like `using System.Web.Http;` but still error is shown, and according to MSDN it has definition for the method `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` [msdn document about this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.globalconfiguration%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), and 
[I am referring this page to upgrade my MVC4 application to MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need System.Web.Http.WebHost if I remember correctly.

In your package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

if already installed, try and force a re-install

```
update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) , it helped

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install the package was already installed. I updated the package and force to re-install and then the problem was fixed.